# Deployment of Amazon Linux 2 on Lightsail Container is getting cancelled

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-lightsail, amazon-linux-2

I wanted to deploy the "Amazon Linux 2"-image (public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:2022) on a Lightsail Container.

It takes a while and then the deployment is getting cancelled. This is the log output:

```
`[19/Aug/2022:12:07:25] [deployment:1] Creating your deployment
[19/Aug/2022:12:08:48] [deployment:1] Started 1 new node
[19/Aug/2022:12:09:57] [deployment:1] Started 1 new node
[19/Aug/2022:12:10:56] [deployment:1] Started 1 new node
[19/Aug/2022:12:11:23] [deployment:1] Canceled
`
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards

Frank

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a running task (so an [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or COMMAND), which keeps the docker container on. See also this [AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU8i3bF2BZQZiwKfxGw5CfgQ/how-to-deploy-amazon-linux-on-a-lightsail-container-service)

Comment: How could I run a typical postgres container? IE `registry.hub.docker.com/postgres:14-alpine`